# Is there any residual data from booting from a USB?

Tags: security, privacy, bootable-media

I've been getting ready to boot from a Kali Linux Live Boot USB. Is there any way my privacy can be compromised after I remove the USB by going through logs or otherwise hidden data? If so, is there a way I can prevent it?

Comment: Question is are you only concern about local files?  If network administrator had a reason to they could still monitor the network traffic upstream from said PC.  Say you have a firewall at home, pfsense for example, then all traffic passthrough PFsense regardless of what you do the PC.  There would be nothing you could do to the local PC to 100% stop me monitoring it.  Even if you encrypted it a MITM could be used or I could just ban all non-approved traffic on the firewall.  Try and use encrypted DNS, I will just use firewall to 100% block all encrypted DNS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way my privacy can be compromised after I remove the USB
> by going through logs or otherwise hidden data?

**No.**

Booting any Linux live session from external media makes no changes to the installed OS (in internal drives), if any.

This is always true provided you don't mount any of the internal drives and somehow interact with their contents (files). Modifying any file, regardless of the method, will change some file attributes that can be uncovered by simple forensic methods.

Comment: If you purposely want to *keep* changes (e.g., installing an application), create a *persistent* live USB drive, e.g., https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik But even so the changes will be at the live/installation media.